# MYSQL question - get unique value

Tags: mysql, database, function, logic

Let's say I have these two variables in MySQL

```
SET data1 = "1,2,3,apple,4,5";
SET data2 = "apple,orange,5";
```

How do I get number of items that appears on those two variables?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm interpreting your question correctly, but it sounds like what you want is the intersection of the two variables (the values that they have in common). Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure if SQL is the best language for string manipulation. This has a kind of an anti-pattern smell...

Comment: I'm trying to implement an algorithm on database level. One of the function i'm comparing is number of tags shared between two items. I don't want to use temporary table or access the table directly to compare these tags, so i'm thinking to use string comparison instead, but not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Shoudn't the tags be in a separate table, one tag per row? SQL (any flavour) is really great for those kinds of operations, but is a huge PITA for inline string manipulation.

Comment: MySQL doesn't contain any functionality for separating a delimited string, so you are going to run into a lot of problems with this implementation. Why don't you want to access the tags table directly, it would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Do you need pure SQL or can use tSQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to do this on MySQL-side you can create stored procedure (or stored function) in which:

- create temporary table (because MySQL's stored routines can't handle arrays, so you have to use temporary table as an array)
- create [WHILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/while-statement.html) cycle to parse your strings using *LOCATE()*, *LEFT()* and *RIGHT()* functions ([MySQL Manual: String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html)) inserting every value in temporary table
- perform needed select (with intersections and so on) from this temporary table

But this solution is really far from being elegant. Storing tags in separate table (as mentioned above, one tag per row) is much more preferable.

Comment: Thank you, I've decided to use different approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to explode the list and count the items. The only way to to explode it in you native language manipulating the value:

Example in php:

```
$values = mysql_result();
echo count(explode(",", $values));
```

The other way is to put all tags in a separate table and joining them in a pivot table then you can do something like this:

```
select 
    count(*) 
from 
    items 
join 
    pivot on pivot.item_id = items.id 
join 
    tags on pivot.tag_id = tags.id 
where 
    item.id = {itemid}
```

Comment: yeah - I could do that on PHP, but I want to be able to sort the data based on the algorithm i'm working-on on database layer, so I need to implement exactly the same algo on both PHP + MySQL level. Any idea how you usually do this? Basically, me as a user will have a compatibility number against different things, I've done the scoring on PHP level, but when it came to MySQL, i'm kinda' stuck

Comment: check my edit. Basically you need to put them in a separate table